# remove outlier for each column depending on lower_bound and upper_bound from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

python 3.8, pandas 1.2.4

MRE:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"mean":[3.3, 2.9, 3.2, 5, 3.7, 5.3,5.8, 5.7],
                  "lower_bound":[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
                  "upper_bound":[4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9]})

data = pd.DataFrame({0:[3,2,4,3,0,5,5,3,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     1:[1,3,2,4,5,5,0,6,3,4,2,1,2,3],
                     2:[3,4,2,5,5,4,2,4,3,2,1,2,3,5],
                     3:[1,1,2,3,4,3,9,7,6,7,6,7,7,7],
                     4:[3,2,2,2,1,2,3,4,6,4,6,8,9,0],
                     5:[2,4,5,3,4,6,7,5,3,4,7,8,9,7],
                     6:[3,4,6,6,5,5,7,6,5,7,4,7,8,8],
                     7:[3,4,5,6,6,6,8,7,5,7,5,6,7,5]})
```

for each column in data dataframe, I want to make value NaN if it is not inside range of [lower_bound, upper_bound]

what I expect:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   3   1   3   NaN ..
1   2   3   4   NaN ..
2   4   2   2   2   
3   3   4   5   3   ..
4   NaN NaN 5   4   
5   NaN NaN 4   3   ..          ..
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: +@ replace values outside [lower_bound, upper_bound] with mean value in a dataframe.

Comment: len(a) must match number of columns in data, rows do not have to match. There will always be a mean value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try using [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({"mean": [3.3, 2.9, 3.2, 5, 3.7, 5.3, 5.8, 5.7],
                  "lower_bound": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
                  "upper_bound": [4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9]})

data = pd.DataFrame({0: [3, 2, 4, 3, 0, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                     1: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                     2: [3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5],
                     3: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7],
                     4: [3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 8, 9, 0],
                     5: [2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7],
                     6: [3, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8],
                     7: [3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5]})

mask = (a['lower_bound'] <= data) & (data <= a['upper_bound'])
data = data.where(mask, np.nan)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
      0    1  2    3    4    5    6    7
0   3.0  1.0  3  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   2.0  3.0  4  NaN  NaN  4.0  4.0  NaN
2   4.0  2.0  2  2.0  NaN  5.0  6.0  5.0
3   3.0  4.0  5  3.0  NaN  3.0  6.0  6.0
4   NaN  NaN  5  4.0  NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0
5   NaN  NaN  4  3.0  NaN  6.0  5.0  6.0
6   NaN  NaN  2  NaN  3.0  7.0  7.0  8.0
7   3.0  NaN  4  7.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
8   1.0  3.0  3  6.0  6.0  3.0  5.0  5.0
9   2.0  4.0  2  7.0  4.0  4.0  7.0  7.0
10  3.0  2.0  1  6.0  6.0  7.0  4.0  5.0
11  4.0  1.0  2  7.0  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0
12  NaN  2.0  3  7.0  NaN  9.0  8.0  7.0
13  NaN  3.0  5  7.0  NaN  7.0  8.0  5.0
```

---

Edit: replace with `mean` option:

```py
mask = (a['lower_bound'] <= data) & (data <= a['upper_bound'])
data = data.where(mask, a['mean'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      0    1  2  3    4    5    6    7
0   3.0  1.0  3  5  3.0  5.3  5.8  5.7
1   2.0  3.0  4  5  3.7  4.0  4.0  5.7
2   4.0  2.0  2  2  3.7  5.0  6.0  5.0
3   3.0  4.0  5  3  3.7  3.0  6.0  6.0
4   3.3  2.9  5  4  3.7  4.0  5.0  6.0
5   3.3  2.9  4  3  3.7  6.0  5.0  6.0
6   3.3  2.9  2  5  3.0  7.0  7.0  8.0
7   3.0  2.9  4  7  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
8   1.0  3.0  3  6  6.0  3.0  5.0  5.0
9   2.0  4.0  2  7  4.0  4.0  7.0  7.0
10  3.0  2.0  1  6  6.0  7.0  4.0  5.0
11  4.0  1.0  2  7  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0
12  3.3  2.0  3  7  3.7  9.0  8.0  7.0
13  3.3  3.0  5  7  3.7  7.0  8.0  5.0
```

Comment: mean values are for each columns in data. mean[0] = 3.3 is mean of first column in data.

Comment: I understand now! Fixed this in my answer.